# How can i search and replace strings in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailmerge

I am trying to write some code which allows me to pass a doc as a string which is either plain txt or html and has some fields embeded i want to replace with personal values. something like for example like this

```
Hi {{ first_name | fallback: "there" }},
```

i will pass the field names as an object with same name so the lookup is easy. So what i am looking for coding ideas how to search for the {{ }} part and then check if field is not unknown, null or "" and if it is apply the fallback value in the tag. 
This is something like mailmerge but i dont want ths to be a docx file and output as word or pdf. i just want the processed string so i can pass back to my mail code and send message

Comment: You need a templating library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Program that will do the following to achieve your output,

1. Get the string enclosed between `{{}}`
2. Split the sting by `|`
3. Remove unwanted space using `trim()`
4. Check and find the `fallback` value
5. `Replace` the sting with desired value

Here is the example program that will do the above operation on step by step.

```
var str = 'Hi {{ first_name | fallback: "there" }},'
var data = {
    first_name: "siva",
    last_name: "sankar",
    code: 29
}

function templateRender(str, data) {
    return str.replace(/{{([^}]+)}}/g, function (match, string) {
        var fallback = ''
        var stringArr = string.split("|");
        var value = stringArr[0].trim();

        if (stringArr[1]) { fallback = stringArr[1].match(/(?<=fallback\:\s?)(["'].*?["'])/)[0].replace(/["']/g, "").trim(); }
        return data[value] ? data[value] : fallback;
    });
}

console.log("New String :::: ", templateRender(str, data));
```

Comment: works like a charm and is small and does not need handlebar or so

Answer (score 1):

Look at HandlebarsJs. It is exactly what Handlebars does, https://handlebarsjs.com

For your fallback you can use if.

```
{{#if first_name}}{{first_name}}{{else}}there{{/if}},
```

Which will default to there if first_name is falsey.

If you think if is a bit verbose you can write a helper function for defaults.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('fallback', (val, def) => val || def);
```

and use it in a template

```
Hi {{fallback first_name 'there'}},
```

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(`Hi {{#if first_name}}{{first_name}}{{ else }}there{{/if}},`);
console.log(template({ first_name: '' }));
console.log(template({ first_name: 'Billy' }));

Handlebars.registerHelper('fallback', (val, def) => val || def);

const templateWithFallback = Handlebars.compile(`Hi {{fallback first_name 'there'}},`);

console.log(templateWithFallback({ first_name: '' }));
console.log(templateWithFallback({ first_name: 'Billy' }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.1.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```